# Keycloak redirecting to Hostname but with port number too

Tags: redirect, keycloak, hostname

I have configured nginx and given hostname to keycloak as `http://keycloak.formsflow.ai` for localhost:8080, but as I see in redirection url it show port number `8080`, how can I remove it?

[Keycloak showing port number in redirection along with hostname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vCTN.png)
Below is my docker config for keycloak

> 

```
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:14.0.0
    container_name: keycloak
    volumes:
      - ./configuration/imports:/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports
    command: 
      - "-b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement=0.0.0.0 -Dkeycloak.import=/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/formsflow-ai-realm.json -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING"
    environment:
      - DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES
      - DB_ADDR=keycloak-db
      - KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME=keycloak.formsflow.ai
      - DB_DATABASE=${KEYCLOAK_JDBC_DB:-keycloak}
      - DB_USER=${KEYCLOAK_JDBC_USER:-admin}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_JDBC_PASSWORD:-changeme}
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USERNAME:-admin}
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD:-changeme}
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

config to set for keycloak to remove port number from redirection url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When behind a reverse proxy, configure Keycloak properties:

- `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true`
- `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=http://keycloak.formsflow.ai/auth`

You may also need to configure headers `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-Host` in Nginx.

Comment: `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=http://keycloak.formsflow.ai/auth`
is woerking